# Memory Pressure in ARC ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I am developing an ipad app.
There is only pushing view from another view no poping. At some point app is terminating due to memory pressure. I debugged using Product -- >Profile Instuments.
In every view there are many allocations of images recording videos etc. and from every view around 80-100mb is getting allocated and when it reaches near 400 mb app is crashing.

Is there any way to de allocate memory in ARC when a view is disappeared ?
I Tried object = Nil; but not working.

Please help me I am searching for this for last 2 days.

Work flow -->  This is an app like submitting personal details
First view selecting some data from a table view - then Face video record -then body video record -  then room video record - and some form submission - at last uploading view

Comment: Your issue is that you continually are pushing views. You are creating a navigation stack that iOS has to remember in case you ever hit the back button. If you want iOS to reclaim the memory, you need to remove pointers to the VC (i.e. pop them). You can also nil out your images/recording videos/allocations on viewWillDisappear and reinitialize them on viewWillAppear. But having a huge navigation stack will still eventually cause you memory issues

Comment: Thanks LyricalPanda - If I popToRootView from any of the view, will the all allocated memory get released ??

Comment: Check my answer about cache of `imageNamed:` method. 
If you didn't use it, then answer is Yes, 
if, of course, you have no leaks :)

Comment: @SplatterStrikes While popToRootview will fix a lot of the allocated memory issues + the fix to arturdev, this really seems like a workflow issue. Why are you continually pushing VCs without popping? How does your workflow work? You haven't given us a lot of info to help you with. We can tell you how to reduce memory issues, but what you really need is a better workflow imo

Comment: @arturdev Hi Yes many places I am using imagenamed: to load big images. But when I changed it to [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: nothing is displaying.

Comment: Ah, sorry, check edited answer. 
replace `dataWithContentsOfFile` with `pathForResource`

Comment: Great - Thank you guys I made it working with out crashing, before every push I am poping to RootView and pushing to specific views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading images like:
`[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];`
Then the memory for this image will not deallocated, because `imageNamed:` cache the image.
This method is useful for showing some small icons,avatars, etc.
So, if you must show many big images, then use
`UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png"];`
This will not cache the image and memory will deallocated when retain count will equal to 0 for that object.

Besides that, when you only push a view controller without pop it in future, then the view controller will never deallocated and will always take a place in memory until the app will not crashed/killed, or until the ViewController who holds that view controller will not deallocated.

So, always make sure that you deallocated the viewController if there is no more need of it (i.e. pop it if it was pushed, or dismiss it in case if it was presented modally) and then show your next view controller.

Comment: Instead of using `-dataWithContentsOfFile:`, I would suggest using `-dataWithContentsOfFile:options:`, and use the `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe`, so that you don't have the overhead of copying around the file's data to user-space until UIImage reads it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a navigation controller that you are pushing views onto. If so you shouldn't be pushing views if you are not popping them. Basically don't use the navigation controller and just transition between view controllers as you go through the UI. Use presentViewController, choose your transition style and make the presentation style fullscreen ought to work.